# Is calling ReentrantReadWriteLock#lock() within the catch block wrong?

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, java.util.concurrent

In the current issue of the German Java Magazine there is a code example how `ReentrantReadWriteLock` (I guess `ReadWriteLock` in general) is often used incorrectly. Unfortunately the author does not care to explain why.

```
private static final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

// #1: correct use
lock.writeLock().lock(); 
try {
  // do stuff 
} finally {
  lock.writeLock().unlock();
}

// #2: incorrect use
try {
  lock.writeLock().lock(); 
  // do stuff 
} finally {
  lock.writeLock().unlock();
}

// #3: incorrect use
lock.writeLock().lock(); 
// do stuff 
lock.writeLock().unlock();
```

I can see why #3 is wrong. **But whats the difference between #1 and #2?** Assuming that `lock.writeLock().lock();` does not throw *(edit: wrong assumption, see the accepted answer)*, these versions look equal to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the [Javadoc for `Lock.lock()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#lock%28%29)

> **Implementation Considerations**
>
> A Lock implementation may be able to detect erroneous use of the lock,
>   such as an invocation that would cause deadlock, and **may throw an
>   (unchecked) exception in such circumstances**. The circumstances and the
>   exception type must be documented by that Lock implementation.

Emphasis mine.

So by the contract it is allowed to throw an `Exception`. This explains why the the second approach is wrong.

Comment: Ah I see, did not catch that. So I guess calling `unlock()` after an unsuccessful `lock()` is not allowed?. Nvm: `A Lock implementation will usually impose restrictions on which thread can release a lock (typically only the holder of the lock can release it) and may throw an (unchecked) exception if the restriction is violated. Any restrictions and the exception type must be documented by that Lock implementation.`

Comment: @atamanroman the lock is reentrant - if your `Thread` holds two locks and accidentally unlocks the wrong one... And yeah, the implementation is free to throw an unchecked exception if you try and unlock without holding the lock.